# Lighting in pseudo 2D game

Tags: light, 2d

In my scene i have 3 objects that are in exact distance from light source (camera is always in the same position). I want to every object to be affected by light in exactly same way, but as you can see, bottom right object is dark:

[image]

For more reference: top row is rendered exactly how I want. I need bottom row to be exactly as a top row:
[image]

Is there a material that will not take into account surface normal vectors to calculate final colour? So I can get effect the same like for example Don't Starve? As you can see bush below fireplace is visible instead we are looking at the side in opposite of lightsource:

[image]

Comment: Hello. Do you want to use Eevee or Cycles? Is there several light sources?

Comment: Hello, in final result I need to export scene to render it in OpenGL (I'm using three js), so my question is more about material, that ignore normal vectors, rather than how create this effect in blender Eevee/Cycles. In the game there will be many light sources

Comment: I don't think (but... we'll see if any answer) you can set it up in Blender so that it works directly in openGL Most likely, you'll have to handle that in openGL (a gradient disk overlay around the light sources).

Comment: That seems like it'd be a solution you'd build in the game engine, rather than something that arises out of the material itself.